# Force Grails to remake link

Tags: grails, internationalization, url-mapping

I need to override the default behavior of Grails when generate link. The purpose is to have url changed base on the current locale.

I have successfully override the DefaultUrlMappingsHolder, but it just work on the first web request when the link is created first time. Grails seems to store the link some where, so the next time I make `createLink` to the same controller and action, it just show the link without re-run the process to create the link. Thus the link is not changed when the locale is changed.

What I've done:

- Create UrlMapping for each language. For example `http://myapp/search` and `http://myapp/suche` both point to 'SearchController'
- Override the DefaultUrlMappingsHolder, when a link is create via reverse url mapping, it take the locale into account and pick the correct urlmapping for each locale and create the correct url.

What should I do to stop this behavior of Grails and force link generation to run again?

Thanks.

Comment: how did you override the DefaultUrlMappingsHolder?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Grails do you installed? There is a [jira](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3385?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel) about it in Grails. It is fixed in a later version.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't this I have the same problem in that jira.

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.0.1
In my case the `getReverseMapping` works fine, but just when the link is created first time. When I refresh or go to another page that have the same link, `getReverseMapping` is no longer triggered. I want `getReverseMapping` run every time a link is render, so link is changed when the locale is changed.